# не работает функция, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, discord

Вот ошибка:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'

Вот код:

```
@work.error
async def workero(interaction, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    delta = timedelta(seconds=error.retry_after)
    await interaction.send(f"Попробуйте в {disnake.utils.format_dt(delta, 't')}")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Всегда проверяйте соотвествие типов в таких ситуациях. Смотрите, что функция требует, и что получает на входе. Анализируйте текст ошибки.

В данном случае анализ говорит, что:
`disnake.utils.format_dt(delta, 't')` никак не ожидает  `datetime.timedelta` на входе. А `timedelta`, судя по названию, в таком формате выдает результат (проверил по https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-datetime-python/klass-timedelta-modulja-datetime/ - так и есть).

Как минимум, тут надо преобразовать тип передаваемых данных - `delta`
в ожидаемый тип (поможет ли - зависит от логики работы).

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ  решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)